# Microchip XC16 : Can we access Port using its address ?? for ex : &PortA?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mplab, xc16

As my question says, to access Port by its address, Can we write it as **"&PORTA"** ??

In my problem, I want to read/write port value from/to **HMI**, using **Modbus Protocol**.

I have an array of structure :

```
typedef struct func_code_reg {
    volatile uint16_t addr;
    volatile uint16_t *data;
}RW_REG_DATA;

// described as
RW_REG_DATA rwCoilStatusTbl[] = {
    //      Addr        Data_Register
    {       0,           &rwCoil_0000      },
    {       1,           &rwCoil_0001      },
};
```

Whenever HMI reads data , it reads the current value of register **&rwCoil_000x**

Whenever HMI writes data, the register **&rwCoil_000x** gets updated.

Instead, I would like to use **&PORTA** to read Port status or to update Port Status.

Is it possible ?? & if possible, is it the correct way to update the Port status ??

Or any better way, please guide me.

(I am using dsPic33E series)

Comment: What is value of `&rwCoil_0000` or `&rwCoil_0001`? Is it mapped to some port?

Comment: @Swanand, &rwCoil_000x is a 16bit register. It is not yet mapped with Port. I am not getting the way to map it with Port as the value of rwCoil_000x will be updated randomly.

Comment: Again, What is value of &rwCoil_0000 or &rwCoil_0001?

Comment: @Swanand, consider rwCoil_0000 = 0x55 & rwCoil_0001 = 0xAA

Comment: And I am assuming you have declared rwCoil_0000 as uint16_t variable

Comment: Yes. "volatile uint16_t rwCoil_0000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PORTx` is already mapped to the contents of the PORTx register, you don't need its address. To read from a port, use the PORTx register. To write, use the LATx register.

So if you want the value `rwCoil_000x` to be reflected on a port (A), simply write:

```
LATA = rwCoil_000x;
```

And if you want to read from the port into the same variable, write:

```
rwCoil_000x = PORTA;
```

Of course, this assumes PORTA is set to be a general purpose output.

Comment: I dont know when will rwCoil_000x value will be changed from HMI. So, How can I write : ** LATA = rwCoil_000x ** ?? I should be aware when to do this ?? Can you guide bit more on this ??? HMI sends request packet to read/write randomly in case of each register.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Even though you don't know *when* the HMI will do a write, it *will* do a write, so that's when you update the output value via the LATx register. If this doesn't make sense, then I'm wrongly assuming your hardware setup and you need to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize over many different ports, you can build an array of volatile references to *PORT.

I did this once for the other way, the outputs, LAT registers, see [Using an array of LATs to toggle outputs. type of (byte) pointer to lat](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m794597.aspx)

Comment: I viewed your link. Just one thing...did **&LATA** worked in your case ??? Means As an array of structure, if i write it as **{ 1, &LATA }**, it should be written to the PortA whenever a request has been sent from HMI ??

Comment: No, you need the bitmask system. bit numbers don't work, that's what I tried originally with the asm routine and that is not fast. PORTA is for reading btw.